# Update sql query does not update records thru mysqli_query() in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I execute `update` query in php thru `mysqli_query()`, but the `update` query **does not update records** in php script, though the same query **does update records** when run inside phpmyadmin... Why? The query result is 1, no errors.
Example:

```
UPDATE `tarex_yhibu` SET `phone` = '7777777777' 
WHERE url = "http://protechautoglass.com/".
```

### Script

```
<?php
$start=microtime(true);
include('../lib.php');
include('../lib/dbconnection.php'); 

echo '<hr>';
$db_handler = init_db();
echo 'db connection is ok!<br />';
// var_dump($db_handler);
try { 
    $records = getTableFields($db_handler, 'tarex_yhibu', ['id','url'], 'phone="" limit 1');
    // echo '<pre>' . print_r($records, true) . '</pre>';

} catch  (Exception $e) {
    echo 'exception: ',  $e->faultstring;
} 

// $res=get_web_page($urls[0]); 
$regex='/tel:([+\d]+)/'; 
echo '<table border=1><tr><th>Url</th><th>Phone</th><th>dump</th><tr>';
foreach($records as $record){
     $res=get_web_page($record['url']);
     preg_match($regex, $res['content'], $matches);
     echo '<tr><td>', $record['url'], '</td><td><b> ' , print_r($matches[1], true), '</b></td><td><b> ' , var_dump($matches[1] ) , '</b></td></tr>';
     settype($matches[1], 'string');
     $phone = (string)$matches[1];
     settype($record['url'], 'string');
     UpdateRecord($db_handler, 'tarex_yhibu', 'phone', $phone,  'url = "' . $record['url'] . '" ' );
}
echo '</tr></table>';
echo '<br >Script execution time  ' , round((microtime(true) - $start),  1), ' seconds.'; //value in seconds
```

### dbconnection.php

```
    function UpdateRecord($db_handler, $tableName, $field, $value, $condition = '1 = 0' )// we set the false condition to prevent occasional update of all the records (when WHERE <condition> is missing)
{
    $query = "UPDATE `{$tableName}` SET `{$field}` = '{$value}' WHERE {$condition} ";
    $result = mysqli_query($db_handler, $query) or trigger_error("Query: $query\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($db_handler)); 
    if (!$result) {
        echo '<br />Update query - Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
        exit;
    } else 
        echo '<br />Result: ', $result;
        echo '<br />Query: ', $query;
        printf("<br />Affected rows (by UPDATE query): ", mysqli_affected_rows($db_handler), '</br>');
}
```

User privileges are ok for the user `srv50213_igor`, see the shot: http://joxi.net/gmvjN1qsx3Xjbm

What's the problem?

### Update

I've changed `"` to `'` and have removed backticks with no avail:
http://joxi.ru/bmoOyo7IQygKmy

Comment: Maybe the error is in the quotes.

Comment: Where 'url' = "http://....." i tihnk

Comment: can you show the script ?

Answer (score 0):

Ths should work in PHP

```
$query = "UPDATE tarex_yhibu SET phone = '7777777777' WHERE url = 'http://protechautoglass.com/';";
```

Simply remove the backticks, PHP does not like them